# How to add Custom Top Links in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, layout, template, toplinks

Hello Can you help me on how to add custom top links in the header area of Magento 2,

Like this: [image: Header Links]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can manage this using Static Block. In your theme `default.xml` you can add new static block.
File Path : `Custom\tutorial\Magento_Theme\layout\default.xml`

```
<referenceBlock name="header.panel">
<block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="header_promo_top">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">header_promo_top</argument>
    </arguments>
</block>
</referenceBlock>
```

Here `header_promo_top` is your static block that will contain your content.

Magento 2  default theme uses`header.panel` Container for showing languages switcher and skip content block in Top bar. You can get more idea about this using the below file:
`vendor\magento\module-theme\view\frontend\layout\default.xml`

Comment: Hello Pankaj, Thank you for this answer of yours. I will try this one. 

I have another question. Is it possible to create toplinks using modules?

Comment: yes it is possible

Comment: Hello Pankaj, Thank you so much you solved my problem. :)

Comment: Can you teach me on how to create blocks using module? and what's the the difference when you use static blocks and module?

Comment: I would suggest you to try at your own using online blocks and tutorials and if you face any issue you can post your questions on SO. some one or may be I will definitely help you

Comment: Thank you sir. I will ask you if I encounter problems along the way with my exploration in magento 2.